# HTML5 Video to Canvas. Cant save the image

Tags: html, video, canvas

The problem I am having is the following:

I use a **video and a canvas tag** and **capture a frame from the video tag** and **place it into the canvas tag**, but when I **create a reference of the canvas in javascript so that I may return** the **dataURL it bombs out**. Please note the **video is local**, is this setting the canvas origin-clean flag to false even though it is local? I have tested in Firfox 3.6, IE9 Beta, Safari 5.0.3 and it fails on each of them.

Here is the code I use to place the frame from the video:

---

```
var video = document.getElementById(“video”);

var canvasDraw = document.getElementById(‘imageView’);
var w = canvasDraw.width;
var h = canvasDraw.height;
var ctxDraw = canvasDraw.getContext(’2d’);

ctxDraw.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
ctxDraw.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
ctxDraw.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
```

---

The above works perfectly.
Below is the code to get the dataURL:

---

```
function getURIformcanvas() {
var ImageURItoShow = “”;
var canvasFromVideo = document.getElementById(“imageView”);
if (canvasFromVideo.getContext) {
var ctx = canvasFromVideo.getContext(“2d”); // Get the context for the canvas.

var ImageURItoShow = canvasFromVideo.toDataURL(“image/png”); //<– It fails on this line.
}
var doc = document.getElementById("txtUriShow");
doc.value = ImageURItoShow;

}
```

---

It always fails on the line:

```
var ImageURItoShow = canvasFromVideo.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Any thought on what might be the problem. If I load a normal image into the canvas it works fine, but as soon as I load the image from video into the canvas that line fails.

Any ideas?

Here is the complete page code, to reproduce the error follow the following steps:

1. **Click the "Capture" button**. (an image will be captured from the video, **very important to do this first!!**)
2. **Click the "View URI" button**. (this is supposed to create the toDataURL of the video image in the canvas and place it in the textbox, but it does not work)

   <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Video.aspx.vb" Inherits="Video" %>

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta content="" charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Video to Canvas</title>

    </head>
    <body>


    <script type="text/javascript">

   </script>
   <table>
      <tr>
          <td>
          <p style="height:21px"></p>
              <video id="video" width="400px" height="300px" controls="true">
                   <source src="gizmo.mp4">
                   <source src="gizmo.ogv">
                  <source src="gizmo.webm">
               </video><br/>
               <button onclick="capture()" style="width: 64px;border: solid
   2px #ccc;">Capture</button><br/>




          </td>
          <td style="vertical-align:top">

      <button onclick="getURIformcanvas()" style="width: 64px;border: solid
   2px #ccc;">View URI</button></p>
      <div id="container" style="border:none">

        <canvas id="imageView" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
   z-index: 0;border:none" width="400" height="300">
          <p>Unfortunately, your browser is currently unsupported by our web 
          application.  We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please use one of
   the 
          supported browsers listed below, or draw the image you want using an

          offline tool.</p>
          <p>Supported browsers: <a href="http://www.opera.com">Opera</a>, <a 
            href="http://www.mozilla.com">Firefox</a>, <a 
            href="http://www.apple.com/safari">Safari</a>, and <a 
            href="http://www.konqueror.org">Konqueror</a>.</p>
        </canvas>

          </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
              <input type="text" id="txtUriShow" name="txtUriShow" value="" />
              <img type="text" id="img1" name="img1" value="" />
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>


      <script>


          function getURIformcanvas() {
              var ImageURItoShow = "";
              var canvasFromVideo = document.getElementById("imageView");
              if (canvasFromVideo.getContext) {
                  var ctx = canvasFromVideo.getContext("2d"); // Get the context for the canvas.canvasFromVideo.
                  var ImageURItoShow = canvasFromVideo.toDataURL("image/png");

              }
              var doc = document.getElementById("txtUriShow");
              doc.value = ImageURItoShow;


          }

          var videoId = 'video';


          function capture() {
              var video = document.getElementById("video");


              var canvasDraw = document.getElementById('imageView');
              var w = canvasDraw.width;
              var h = canvasDraw.height;
              var ctxDraw = canvasDraw.getContext('2d');

              ctxDraw.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

              ctxDraw.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
              ctxDraw.save();



          }




      </script>

    </body>
   </html>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

These files are local in you HDD, or by local you mean that the video is in the same folder as the html/js files?
You have to put all the files somewhere in the web to test it appropriately.

Comment: @UVL Yes these files are local, in the same folder as the .aspx .js etc files, I am running this off my local machine and have not hosted it on a server yet. Would it have an effect as I am testing it in Visual Studio

Comment: I noticed that this doesn't work while working in the "file://" protocol. But on a local IIS server (so localhost or 127.0.0.1) should work. (but I don't have a local server to try BTW)

Comment: +1 Safari happens to treat `file://` as origin-clean, but Chrome and Firefox do not. You need browse from `http://` if you want to test it properly.

Comment: UPDATE: This seems to be due to the origin-clean flag of the canvas, it marks the canvas flag as **origin-clean = false** if you **draw to the canvas from a video**. I agree they should block obtaining the pixel data from an image drawn from an external url video, but surely they should allow you to manipulate an image obtained from a video that is local to your website (**If only there was a way around this????**). How do I get hold of W3C or the main developers of most of the browsers (Firefox, safari, IE9) so that I can suggest this to them? :)

Comment: @brad Get in touch with them [on the WHATWG mailing list](http://lists.whatwg.org/listinfo.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org)